# Replacing index vector with levels

Tags: r, vector

What I need is a way to replace the elements in an index vector with new ones. This is just dummt data:

```
index <- sample(1:4, 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

Note that what I'm looking for should also work for

```
index <- sample(c("one", "two", "duck", "something"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

I want to replace the `1:4` elements with something like:

```
cols <- c("black", "red", "green", "blue")
```

What I want would be:

```
> index
[1] 1 4 3 3 2 4 1 ...

> result
[1] "black" "blue" "green" "green" "red" "blue" "black" ...
```

I believe I saw a function that did that a while back, but I can't remember what it was. `gsub()` doesn't work because it only does one; `replace` doesn't either, etc. I'm really looking forward for the function I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a numeric index from `sample`ing.  So just use `[` to replace those index with a vector of values where "black" will replace the `1`, "red", the `2`, "green", the 3rd, and so on...

```
cols <- c("black", "red", "green", "blue")
index <- sample(1:4, 1000, replace = TRUE)
cols[index]
```

If the index is

```
index <- sample(c("one", "two", "duck", "something"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

change the 'cols' to a named vector and then do the replacement

```
setNames(cols, c("one", "two", "duck", "something"))[index]
```

Comment: Oh, that's it. The first time I tried it, I did it backwards... `index[cols]`. Of course I thought it didn't make any sense... Yeah, that's it.

Comment: @ÉricoPatto thanks.  I updated for the second case with character 'index'